# Spring boot create multiple mocks of the same interface doesn't work with constructor

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test

I try to implement MockitoExtension in Spring Boot with a simple service class. When I implement it via field-set, it works. But when I implement it constructor, i doesn't work.

ExampleService:

```
@Service
public class ExampleService
{
    private final AmqpTemplate requestTemplate;

    private final AmqpTemplate resultTemplate;

    public ExampleService(@Qualifier("requestTemplate") AmqpTemplate requestTemplate,
                        @Qualifier("resultTemplate") AmqpTemplate resultTemplate)
    {
        this.requestTemplate = requestTemplate;
        this.resultTemplate = resultTemplate;
    }
}
```

ExampleServiceTest:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ExampleServiceTest
{
    @InjectMocks
    private ExampleService exampleService;

    @Mock(name = "requestTemplate")
    private AmqpTemplate requestTemplate;

    @Mock(name = "resultTemplate")
    private AmqpTemplate resultTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

requestTemplate and resultTemplate looks like same object on test cases and it behaves wrong...

When I implement it via Autowired, it works...

```
@Service
public class ExampleService
{
    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate requestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate resultTemplate;

    ...
}
```

I wonder the constructor solution and reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: You have `requestQueueTemplate` in the `@Qualifier` and `requestTemplate` in the mock, or is that a typo in the question?

Comment: yes, it is a typo. fixed.

Comment: For me it also doesn't work, so in my test the second mock is working as first. You can get rid of `@InjectMocks` annotation and create intstance of your service: 
`ExampleService exampleService = new ExampleService (requestTemplate, resultTemplate)`
Then it works.